# My menu loop isn't working and I don't know why

Tags: python

I'm writing code for a project and I am just finishing up the menu, where there are 5 options and the user inputs a number to select said option. Here's my code:

```
  display_menu(True)
  command = input("Enter a number (0 to exit): ")
  
  while command != 0:
    if command == 1:
      namefile = input("Enter word list filename: ")
      wordlist = make_list(namefile)
      print('Word list is loaded.')
    elif command == 2:
      namefile = input('Enter movie review filename:')
      moviedict = make_dict(namefile)
      print('Movie reviews are loaded.')
    elif command == 3:
      searchword = input('Enter a word to search: ')
      count1, score1 = search_word(searchword)
      print(searchword + ' appears ' + count1 + ' times')
      print('The average score for the reviews containing the word terrific is: ' + score1)
    elif command == 4:
      print_lists(list, list_scores)
    elif command == 5:
      pass
    display_menu(True)
    command = input("Enter a number (0 to exit): ")
```

it definitely prints the list but when I enter a command input it doesn't actually work.

Comment: Input produce a string but your if, elif expressions are testing for an int value. You need to convert to int or else test for '1' etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command` is a string returned by `input`, and you're comparing to an int. You need to explicitly convert that string to an int.

```
command = int(input("Enter a number (0 to exit): "))
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris said you must not compare string and integer.
You may convert the input to an integer or you can test for an alphabetic choice as in:

```
while command:
  if command == "1"
    ...
```

and, why not, alphanumeric mnemonics:

```
while command:
  if command in ("1", "f", "F")
    ...
  elif command in ("2", "m", "M")
    ...
  elif command in ("3", 'w', "W")
    ...
  elif command in ('4', "l", "L")
    ...
```

Comment: Converting to `int` nicely handles whitespace issues in input. `int('     5    ')` equals `5`, but `'     5    '` does not equal `'5'`.

Comment: That's True Chris. But a "command = strip( input(...))" would do the job nicely"

Comment: Perhaps you meant `input(...).strip()`.